# Can I use Firewire or Thunderbolt cable with this hard drive dock?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, thunderbolt, firewire

I'm an external hard drive docking station: [http://www.amazon.com/Thermaltake-BlacX-eSATA-Docking-Station/dp/B001A4HAFS/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001A4HAFS). I'm currently using the USB2.0 cable that comes with it. I wonder if I could use Firewire or Thunderbolt or USB3.0 to speed up data transfer with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the link provided:

- Supports eSATA Transfer Speed up to 3Gbps
- Supports USB 2.0 Transfer Speed up to 480Mbps

For the 3Gbps transfer speed you will need the [StarTech 6-Feet Shielded External eSATA Cable M/M (ESATA6)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000ENYXZ6)

and the [Thunderbolt to eSATA adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00LOLBBQQ)

Comment: Oops - missed that. Binning my answer ;-))